# How determine what Javascript code triggerd a modal dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, modal-dialog

I have a web page that uses several jQuery plugins.  One of them is popping up a modal dialog box that has the title "Error" and no other information.  I used the "inspect" option in Chrome DevTools to inspect it.  But all I see is some HTML elements and not much else to help me figure who is popping up this modal dialog box (see HTML snippet below)>

Is there a way to use Chrome DevTools to have it break into the debugger when any modal dialog box is popped up?

Here is the dialog box's HTML:

[image: HTML for modal dialog box]

Comment: I believe you are looking for: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ You can also add breakpoints in JS: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?